# Can I subscribe to a 'logs' event notifying the transaction is done with web3.js?

Tags: web3js

I'm using web3.js library to subscribe to ERC20 token transfer events on a blockchain:

```
const logOptions = {
   // Filter transfer topics 
   topics: [
       web3.utils.sha3('Transfer(address,address,uint256)')
   ]
};

let subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', logOptions);

subscription.on('data', async (event: any) => {
    // `event` contains the transfer info
});
```

I get an event emitted for any transfer triggered by a transaction, but I wish I would get an event saying the transaction is done - which means all transfers were made.

Any way to it using web3.js, or maybe another library?

Answer (score 1):

Logs are not emitted until a transaction is mined in a block. This is the common definition to see when a transaction is done.

Thus, the code you describe works correctly and only sees logs from done transactions.

Comment: So, can I know when all of the logs are emitted(and I can return from my function for example)?
I guess I can use `setTimeout(()=>{ ... }, 50)` if we can assume that all of the logs emitted at the same time, but I', looking for a more elegant method, like an "allLogsEmitted" event.